Fo inline line-through does not strike out text in XSL which formats XML to XLS (excel) file
Using a Xsl stylesheet I am formatting output XML file (obtained from my tool) to Excel (xls file). In that, I just want to strike through a text. I am using fo:inline for that like following:
   <fo:block>
     <fo:inline text-decoration="line-through">Hello World</fo:inline>
     </fo:block>

But this is not working, what can I be using wrong here? Any hint will be very useful.
Just for testing I tried using underline decoration but that is also not working.
My Xsl:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
        xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"
        xmlns:fo="https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_flow"
        xmlns:format="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
            
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="generateReportPage">
            <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Report'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="subtitle1" select="'Overview'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="generateReportPage">
            <xsl:param name="title"/>
            <xsl:param name="subtitle1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="changeSummaryEle" select="/plm:PLMXML/plm:ChangeSummaryElement"/>
            <xsl:processing-instruction name="mso-application">progid="Excel.Sheet"</xsl:processing-instruction>
            
            <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
        xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="heading1">
          <Font ss:Color="#0000FF" ss:Size="20" ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Bold="1"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#CCCCFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="heading2">
          <Font ss:Color="#0000FF" ss:Size="12" ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Bold="1"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#CCCCFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="heading3">
          <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left"/>
          <Font ss:Color="#000000" ss:Size="10" ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Bold="1"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#CCCCFF" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="cell_data">
          <Font ss:Color="#000000"/>
          <Interior ss:Color="#FFFFCC" ss:Pattern="Solid"/>
        </Style>
      </Styles>

      <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">

        <Table>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="60" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="60" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="100" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>
          <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="80" AutoFitWidth="1"/>

          <Row>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="heading1">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="heading1"></Cell>
          </Row>
          <Row></Row>
          <Row>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="heading2">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                <xsl:value-of select="$subtitle1"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="heading2"></Cell>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="heading3">
              <Data ss:Type="String">
                Date: 
                </Data>
                    </Cell> 
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="heading3">
                    <Data ss:Type="String"> 
                <xsl:value-of select="$report_date"/>
              </Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="heading2"></Cell>
          </Row>
          <Row></Row>   
            <xsl:variable name="occStr">
                        <xsl:text>Hello Application</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:variable>

            <xsl:call-template name="createCL">
            <xsl:with-param name="occStr" select="$occStr"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </Table>
      </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="createCL">
            <xsl:param name="occid"/>
        <xsl:variable name="strikedOldValue">
        <fo:block>
        <fo:inline text-decoration="line-through">Hello World</fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="displayValue">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($occid, ' ', $strikedOldValue)" />
        </xsl:variable> 
        <Data ss:Type="String">
        <div>
        <xsl:value-of select ="$displayValue"/>
        </div>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>



So you have some XSLT transformation that is supposed to output some XML format that Excel can process? What does XSL-FO have to do with that? It all seems to some wild mix of XML for Excel, of HTML and of XSL-FO; which tool do you expect to process that format, is Excel supposed to process XSL-FO?

Sorry if my explanation is unclear. I am writing data from XML to excel (as excel is user understandable format). Just want to strike out certain text using fo:inline. My excel gets all text correctly just text decoration like line-through is not applied.

If Excel is the target application, why do you use XSL-FO? Do you expect Excel to interpret/process a fo:inline text-decoration="line-through" to render text stroke through or where do you expect to get that rendering from? Why is the question tagged as apache-fop, do you use that at all?

I also don't see what does XSL_FO have to do with this.
Apparently you are trying to produce a file in the Excel 2002/2003 XML format. I believe that you need to define a style in the Styles element as:
        <Style ss:ID="strike">
          <Font ss:StrikeThrough="1"/>
        </Style>

and then format the cell as:
                <Cell ss:StyleID="strike">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$yourtext"/>
                    </Data>
                </Cell>

Untested because I don't have Excel.
